# Find the 2nd highest no from array, where array contains duplicate values

Tags: java, arrays

```java
public class Second_Largest_Number_In_Array_with_Dupes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {6,8,2,4,3,1,5,7}; 
        
        int temp ;  
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++){
                if (a[i] < a[j]){
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Second Largest element is " + a[1]);
    }
}
```

This only works for array with no duplicate values.

For example it does not work for this array: `int[] a = {6,8,2,4,3,1,5,7,8};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to the correct answer, one can also use the following algorithm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a= {6,8,2,4,3,1,5,7,8} ;
    SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Arrays.stream(a).forEach(sortedSet::add);
    sortedSet.remove(sortedSet.last());
    System.out.println(sortedSet.last());
}
```

Add to a sorted set, so that the highest values will be at the end of that set. Moreover, by using a set we are removing any duplicated values. To get the highest element one would do `sorted_set.last()`, for the second highest one has to first remove the last element.

One can generalize the function to any `nth` max element, like so:

```
public static int getNthMaxElement(int [] array, int nth){
    SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(sortedSet::add);
    if(array.length < nth) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 1; i < nth; i++)
        sortedSet.remove(sortedSet.last());
    return sortedSet.last();
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a= {6,8,2,4,3,1,5,7,8} ;
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.println(i+"th max : "+getNthMaxElement(a, i));
}
```

**output:**

```
1th max : 8
2th max : 7
3th max : 6
4th max : 5
5th max : 4
6th max : 3
7th max : 2
8th max : 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

- Initialize max and second_max with the lowest possible value `Integer.MIN_Value`
- Then go through your array and check for each element if it is greater then the `max_value` -> When yes reassign your max_value with a[i] and reassign your second_max_value with max_malue

---

```
 if (a[i] > max) {
                temp = max;
                max = a[i];
                second_max = temp;
```

- Then check if your a[i] is greater then your second_max_value and not equal to your max_value . If yes reassign your second_max_value with a[i]

  `a[i] > second_max && a[i] != max`
- Last but not least check if second_max is equal to the initial value

  If yes then there is no second highest Value in your Array. Example Arrays for this case
  {5, 5, 5}, {1}
  @Thanks to Henry

Here the Code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7 };
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int second_max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > max) {
                temp = max;
                max = a[i];
                second_max = temp;
            } else if (a[i] > second_max && a[i] != max) {
                second_max = a[i];
            }
        }
        if (second_max == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("No Second Highest value");
        } else {
            System.out.println(second_max);
        }
}
```

#### Output

7

Comment: Ty for the advice, there is a need for a case when a[i] is not greater then the highest but a[i] is greater then the second highest. I uptated it

Comment: But i need 7, as second highest is 7

Comment: then get rid of <= and do <. In the second if do only the assignment when a[i] != max

Comment: @HarshaA I have updated my example try it out

Comment: You're welcome, but consider for arrays of length 1 it will not work because they have no second highest. you should catch this

Comment: I added that every every array below the length of 2 will not considered

Comment: There are also arrays longer than 2 that don't have a second largest element: e.g. `{5,5,5}`.

Comment: @Henry True didn't considered, to solve this you can do a check before printing if second_max == Integer_MIN_VALUE, if yes this means the value was not set

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of java inbuild collection.
For that you need a structure that retain values with no duplicates and also store values in order 
(eg: natural-order, ascending this case).

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MinArr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8 };
        SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            set.add(a[i]);
        }
        set.forEach(System.out::println);
        if (set.size() >= 2) {
            set.remove(set.last());
            System.out.println("second max is =" + set.last());
        } else {
            System.out.println("there is no second max");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
//list values
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
second max is =7
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get k highest number in the array if space is not a constraint then we can use priority queue.

```
 int[] a = {6,8,2,4,3,1,5,7}; 
        
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pr = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            pr.add(a[i]);
        }
        pr.poll();
        System.out.println(pr.poll());``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8};
    TreeSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>();
    stream(a).forEach(sortedSet::add);
    sortedSet.remove(sortedSet.last());
    System.out.println(sortedSet.last());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

***Here is what i came up with, different from the ones above***

```
public class SecondLargestNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] nums = {1,8,8,5,7,9,9,-1,-5,1,7};
        
        int arrsize = nums.length;
        
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        
        int[] sortedarry = new int[arrsize];
        
        for(int i=0; i<arrsize; i++){
            sortedarry[i] = nums[arrsize - i -1];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i <arrsize; i++){
            if(sortedarry[i] != sortedarry[i+1]){
                System.out.println("Second largest number is: "+sortedarry[i+1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***COULD HELP ANYONE ELSE!! ***

Comment: Try adding comments to your code to explain what it's trying to do at each step. This will help others to understand what you intended and then help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using unnecessary collection algorithms or data structures. This problem can be solved just by t**racking the largest and second largest element using two simple variables**, which significantly reduces time complexity compared to sorting or other methods.
Here is the solution in JAVA

public class Second_Largest_Number_In_Array_with_Dupes {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8 };

    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int second_largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            second_largest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] >= second_largest && arr[i] < largest) {
            second_largest = arr[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Second Largest element is " + second_largest);
}
```

}

Comment: how is this solution different from the one posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65651882/85421), more than two years ago? But for the same error as the posted one also had when posted - and corrected... and basically the same error as the question. Have you at least tested? It will return `8`, the first highest value, not the second.